# Ajax: Update Index when Create is successful

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an Index, a GET Create and POST Create action for my Person model. I display the Index in a parent view so it is called as a ChildAction.

What I want to be able to do is also call the GET Create as a ChildAction into the same parent view or into the Index view. Then when the Create form is submitted, I want the Index to be refreshed.

How do I go about implementing this? I have been playing around with this using Ajax.BeginForm but it seems to be posting to the Create action multiple times so I think my attempt is flawed. My main problem is to get the Index action to refresh when the Create POST is successful. What should Create POST return?

All help and advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how this could be set:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MainAction()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessCreate(SomeViewModel model)
    {
        return PartialView("Index");
    }
}
```

and the corresponding views:

`~/Views/Home/MainAction.cshtml`:

```
<div>
    This is the main view
</div>

<div id="indexContainer">
    @{Html.RenderAction("Index");}
</div>
```

`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`:

```
<div>
    This is the index view @DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
</div>

<div>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Create");}
</div>
```

`~/Views/Home/Create.cshtml`:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProcessCreate", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "indexContainer" }))
{
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Also don't forget to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` script for the Ajax.* helpers to work:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You will notice that I have renamed the Create POST action because otherwise when the Html.RenderAction helper is called after postback of the form it will execute the POST action once again and you will end up in an endless loop.

Comment: This is great Darin, thanks. However I cannot return the Index partial from POST ProcessCreate because the Index view needs a viewmodel - the list. I could have my ProcessCreate make the viewmodel but then it is doing the work of the Index action. How do I get around this?

Comment: You externalize this work in a repository or service layer and then call this method in both actions to avoid code repetition.

Comment: Is there no way to force a re-call of the Index action when the ProcessCreate is successful? As in the ProcessCreate returns something, (javascript I'm guessing) which will then trigger this? If so, which of the two methods is the best to pursue? Just wondering as I am an Ajax novice and am looking to improve my understanding.

Comment: In your POST action you could `return Index();` which will invoke the Index action and populate to populate the model. But personally I wouldn't do that. I would refactor the task into reusable methods that could be called from both actions.

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong. My code seems to match yours and I have updated POST Create to ProcessCreate but I am still getting multiple posts per click of the submit button. Any ideas? The only difference is I am using Html.Action rather than RenderAction.

Comment: Fixed! I was referencing jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js directly in the partial. Once moved to the _layout page, its fine! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know whether i understood your prob exactly or not , but i think it may help u
like u use
success : function(data){ ... some code ...}
u also have to use one more attribute here

onComplete : function (data){ ... some code ...}

now simply write the code wht u want to perform after the ajax call is complete .
but write it in the complete function